# SIFT Keypoint to Affine transformation Matrix for Lucas kanade approximation

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I have calculated SIFT Key-points from two different Scenes. I need to give a initial Affine transformation matrix in order to create a template for Lucas Kandae approximation.

Basically take a template image from first scene super impose the template on the next scene. Correct the Keypoint location error.

Any leads for this problem, would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain affine transform from keypoints you need to call opencv function "getAffineTransform(keypoints_vector1, keypoiints_vector2)". This will return you the required matrix. for example:

suppose you have two vectors of keypoints of 2 images:

```
vector<Point2f> vec1;
vector<Point2f> vec2;
```

suppose you have your needed mat of name "affine_mat"

```
Mat affine_mat( 2, 3, CV_32FC1 );
```

you call your opencv function as:

```
 affine_mat= getAffineTransform( vec1, vec2);
```

This affine matrix will help you to proceed with LK method.

Comment: This did not help in my case.  I had to use Hit and trial method to initialize the affine transformation matrix.